# Angular & TypeScript: Class instance check doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to check the type of error that is being returned from the web service. The problem is that `instanceof` check doesn't work. None of the `if` work.

Component class method that triggers the call to WS:

```
public performSearch(keyword: string) {
    this.searchService.searchWithQuery(keyword)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.searchResults = JSON.parse(response._body);
        },
        (error: AppError) => {
          console.log('error instance');
          console.log(error);
          if (error instanceof NotFoundError) {
            this.snackBar.open('404 Not Found', 'X', {
              duration: 5000,
            });
          }
          if (error instanceof AccessDeniedError) {
            this.snackBar.open('401 Access Denied', 'X', {
              duration: 5000,
            });
          }
          if (error instanceof BadInputError) {
            this.snackBar.open('400 Bad Input', 'X', {
              duration: 5000,
            });
          }
          if (error instanceof AppError) {
            this.snackBar.open('General Error', 'X', {
              duration: 5000,
            });
          }
        });
  }
```

search.data.service class that is extending the base service class:

```
searchWithQuery(query: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.tokenValue);
    return this.http.get(this.gatewayUrl + this.serviceName + this.withQuery + query, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response): ErrorObservable {
    if (error.status === 404)
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError(error.json()));
    if (error.status === 400)
      return Observable.throw(new BadInputError(error.json()));
    if (error.status === 401) {
      return Observable.throw(new AccessDeniedError(error.json()));
    }

    return Observable.throw(new AppError(error.json()));
  }
```

AppError.ts class

```
export class AppError {
  constructor(public originalError?: any) {
  }
}
```

And the rest of the error classes just extend it, f.e.:

```
export class AccessDeniedError extends AppError {
}
```

When I am trying to log the `error` of `AppError` I get this in the console which is very odd:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.throw is not a function
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/common/services/search.data.service.ts.SearchDataService.handleError [as selector] (search.data.service.ts:52)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/catch.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catch.js:104)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1231)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1370)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1388)
```

Comment: you should read error messages... They are useful

Comment: @smnbbrv you're very kind ;)

Comment: :D well, this was truth anyway :)

Comment: Truth was that I imported a wrong module. Which was very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error message says, the error is none of the above but `TypeError`, and it is caused by the fact that there's no `Observable.throw` method.

Unless the entire RxJS package was imported with `import 'rxjs/Rx'`, `throw` should be imported explicitly, as any other RxJS operator or observable method:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

This kind of errors is supposed to be detected during TypeScript compilation, so there would be no need to debug them at runtime.

Comment: I had `import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";` and thought it was sufficient, but I guess I was wrong :) Thanks it's now working great!

Comment: You're welcome. It could possibly be enough if were imported somewhere else (often it is), but this kind of conditions shouldn't be relied, it's a good thing to import it everytime you use it - or you can import it once in `polyfills.ts` or other common module.

Comment: Thanks! These kind of advises are very useful.